# I'm trying to make a function to sort ints in an array but i get an error when this code is being ran. Where is my error?

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, sorting

I know that there is a sort property in an array but i was trying to figure out how it was made.

```
var array = [3,6,9,2,1,5,7,4,8]

func sort() {

    for n in array {

        if n < array[array.indexOf(n)! + 1] {

            print("do nothing")


        } else  {

            array[n] = array[n + 1]
            array[n + 1] = array[n]
        }
    }


}

sort()
```

Comment: Most sorting implementations are complex. See https://github.com/jessesquires/swift-sorts for examples in Swift.

Comment: 1) "I get an error" is a pretty vague problem description. 2) Your code to swap two array elements does not work. 3) Use the *debugger* to isolate the problem. Hint: What happens for `n=9`?

Comment: You can also take a look at the logic of some famous sorting alghoritms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: Swift, specifically, uses of introsort (quicksort/heapsort) for all but smaller ranges, see [this source file from the Swift report](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift.gyb) as well as [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677026/swift-sorting-algorithm-implementation) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an index out of bounds error that comes from this line

```
if n < array[array.indexOf(n)! + 1]
```

When n reaches the end of the array, you're trying to access the next element in the array, which doesn't exist because you've already reached the end.

You'll need to check to make sure that it is within the bounds of the array before you access the next element.