# Which general purpose sorting algorithm does Swift use? It does not perform well on sorted data

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, sorting, time-complexity

I have been picking and probing at Swift standard libraries `sort()` function for its `Array` type. To my surprise I have noticed it performs poorly on already-sorted data.

Sorting an array of `Int` which is shuffled seems to be 5x faster than sorting that very same array when it is already sorted. Sorting an array of shuffled objects is about 4x faster than sorting the very same one already in sorted order (sorting object array vs `Int` array use different algorithms I am sure so I sorted both to eliminate bias).

These are the results:

```
Shuffled Int array sort time: 1.3961209654808
Shuffled ColorObject array sort time: 3.14633798599243
NOnshuffled Int array sort time: 7.34714204072952
NOnshuffled ColorObject array sort time: 10.9310839772224
```

For reference below is my code:

```
class ElapsedTimer {

    let startTime: CFAbsoluteTime
    var endTime: CFAbsoluteTime?

    init() {
        startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    }

    func stop() -> CFAbsoluteTime {
        endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        return duration!
    }

    var duration: CFAbsoluteTime? {
        if let endTime = endTime {
            return endTime - startTime
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

public class CountedColor {
    public private(set) var count: Int
    public private(set) var color: UIColor

    public init(color: UIColor, colorCount: Int) {
        self.count = colorCount
        self.color = color
    }
}

var distributedIntArray = [Int]()

for value in 1..<1000000 {
    distributedIntArray.append(value)
}

var distributedCountedColorArray = distributedIntArray.map{ CountedColor(color: UIColor.white, colorCount: $0) }

distributedCountedColorArray.shuffle()
distributedIntArray.shuffle()

var timer = ElapsedTimer()
distributedIntArray.sort()
print("Shuffled Int array sort time: \(timer.stop())")
timer = ElapsedTimer()

distributedCountedColorArray.sort{ return $0.count < $1.count }
print("Shuffled Color array sort time: \(timer.stop())")
timer = ElapsedTimer()

distributedIntArray.sort()
print("NOnshuffled Int array sort time: \(timer.stop())")
timer = ElapsedTimer()

distributedCountedColorArray.sort{ return $0.count < $1.count }
print("Non shuffled Color array sort time: \(timer.stop())")
```

My array `shuffle()` method was pulled from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843647/shuffle-array-swift-3/37843901). My `ElapsedTimer` simply wraps and uses `CACurrentMediaTime()` functions.

My question is why am I seeing this behavior? Especially when I am sorting the object array which should surely be using a general purpose sort. What kind of general purpose sorting algorithm is swift using? It surely can’t be one where the worst case and average case are the same like mergeSort.

Comment: Asking "why" Swift chooses a certain implementation does not make a good objective question - rationale questions rarely do as objective supportive evidence is usually hard to find. Removing the extra cruft will make for a more tidy question. The objective question is "What sort algorithm does Swift use? (What performance can be expected (in xyz cases)?)"

Comment: I believe asking "why" to be a totally valid question. Understanding why an implementation is chosen is just as important if not more, all decisions should be justifiable. That being said I can re-word the question.

Comment: Swift is open source, so if you really want to know what sort algorithm they are using, why don't you look and see? As for your actual question, "why would" is not a good fit for Stack Overflow; it's a matter of opinion why Apple did this or that.

Comment: What is `CountedColor`?

Comment: @YuchenZhong let me edit the question/code snippet to include that

Comment: @matt ok I understand what you are getting at, let me change the wording so its less of an opinionated/philosophical question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift sorting algorithm implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677026/swift-sorting-algorithm-implementation)

Comment: And your implementation of `ElapsedTimer ` is?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Swift uses [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort). Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift.gyb) we see that the chosen pivot is the first element. The wikipedia page on Introsort says:

> (...), one of the critical operations is choosing the pivot: the
>   element around which the list is partitioned. The simplest pivot
>   selection algorithm is to take the first or the last element of the
>   list as the pivot, causing poor behavior for the case of sorted or
>   nearly sorted input.

Thus it is entirely predictable, given the implementation choice, that Swift's sorting performance is worst for sorted inputs.

I have built a complete benchmark for people who want to easily reproduce the OP's claims :
https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/tree/master/extra/swift/sort

For reference, the GNU ISO C++ standard library uses a median-of-3 pivot (as per the `stl_algo.h` header).

Comment: Follow up: if choosing the first item as pivot is a bad choice, what would be a better implementation? Wikipedia mention median of 3 with some caveats. Seems to me it would be harder to come up with a worst case with median of 3 versus first item though.

Answer (score 22):

In the Swift 5 evolution, the IntroSort algorithm was replaced with a modified version TimSort (implemented first in 2002 by Tim Peters for Python) in the 'sort()' method:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift

Answer (score 5):

This is a duplicate of this question it seems: [Swift sorting algorithm implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677026/swift-sorting-algorithm-implementation)

Furthermore the reason why it performs so much better when shuffled is probably just because when its shuffled its performance is not hitting the upper bound of NlogN. Sorting the sorted array probably gets closer to that upper limit so its still all in all the same sort. But I dont know this is just theory

Comment: this is incorrect, the performance of swift’s sort on an already sorted array larger than a few down elements is `O(n**2)`. On a *shuffled* array it comes down to `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: By O(n**2) I assume you mean N squared. How can that be swifts sort is an intro sort, and introSorts worst case complexity is NlogN.

Comment: As evidenced by the OP’s question, it appears swift’s sort does not behave like a proper introsort, or else it would not be vulnerable to ordered input. Perhaps the depth threshold is set very high that it predominantly exhibits quicksort behavior.

Comment: Potentially or the pivot selection  is poor.

Comment: pivot selection only changes which kind of patterned input the sort is vulnerable to. Though last I heard, swift was using the first element, which seems like an extraordinarily *bad* choice considering how common simple-sorted input is…

Comment: I believe last time I checked the open source code it was using the first element. The recursion depth threshold was not some aggregious value so it probably has to be their pivot selection. It would be easy to fix that I believe on their end

Comment: in that case it might be good to bring it up on swift dev because i don't think it’s been mentioned, though i believe they're a bit tied up rn fixing crashers for 3.1

Comment: Hmm will do thanks for the suggestion. Maybe I can submit a PR fixing it? I don't know how long it takes for them to approve code pull request and which route would be faster fixing myself or pinging them about it

Comment: they are usually pretty quick but i don't know if they are accepting changes at this phase in the release cycle atm

Comment: Do they generally announce when they are accepting changes?

Comment: The implementation is here if anyone is interested: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/02e2bd5380af69948d2324b936bfc61e1454d8ea/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift.gyb#L232-L301