# Sort array elements based on their frequency

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, time-complexity

I need to sort an array of elements based on their frequency, for example:

```
Input array: [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]
Expected output: [1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

I tried with the code below:

```
var set: NSCountedSet = [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]

var dictionary = [Int: Int]()
set.forEach { (item) in
    dictionary[item as! Int] = set.count(for: item)
}
dictionary.keys.sorted()
print(dictionary)
```

**Description**: As 1, 3, 4 occur only once, they are shown at the beginning, 2 occurs two times, 5 three times, 6 four times. And [1, 3, 4] are sorted among them.

Expected result: Time complexity should be **O(n)**

Comment: I dont think you can get to O(n) in worst case. If your requirement is that unique items are being sorted as well, that already gives you O(n*log n).

Comment: Count sort is one choice to meet o(n) if the frequency is small

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve the results in `O(nlogn)` time by first creating a `Dictionary` containing the number of occurrences for each element (`O(n)`), then calling `sorted` on the `Array` ([Swift uses Introsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031106/which-general-purpose-sorting-algorithm-does-swift-use-it-does-not-perform-well/41070802), which is `O(nlogn)`) and using the values from the previously created `Dictionary` for the sorting. The elements of your array need to be `Comparable` for sorting to work and `Hashable` to be able to store them in a `Dictionary`, which provides `O(1)` element lookup.

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable & Hashable {
    func sortByNumberOfOccurences() -> [Element] {
        let occurencesDict = self.reduce(into: [Element:Int](), { currentResult, element in
            currentResult[element, default: 0] += 1
        })
        return self.sorted(by: { current, next in occurencesDict[current]! < occurencesDict[next]!})
    }
}

[1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2].sortByNumberOfOccurences() // [1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

The above solution preserves the order of elements that occur an equal number of times. If you actually want to sort such elements based on their compared values (which is what your sample output does), you can modify the closure in `sorted` like below:

```
return self.sorted(by: {occurencesDict[$0]! <= occurencesDict[$1]! && $0 < $1})
```

Or even shorter, [comparing `tuples` for sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612765):

```
return self.sorted(by: {(occurencesDict[$0]!,$0) < (occurencesDict[$1]!,$1)})
```

which produces the sample output you provided, `[1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]`

Comment: I was about to post this `let array = [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]
let freq = array.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }
let sortedArray = array.sorted() {
    freq[$0]! < freq[$1]!
}
sortedArray`

Comment: It cannot be done in O(n). You need to sort this array first, then use the method mentioned above.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri no, you don't need to sort the array first, that's done in the `sorted` call. However, you're right, the overall time complexity of my algorithm is `O(nlogn)`, updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: `sorted(by:)` is not O(n).

Comment: @RobertDresler yes just change the sort to `freq[$0]! <= freq[$1]! && $0 < $1`

Comment: @MartinR you're absolutely right, I was wrong, updated my answer

Comment: @LeoDabus I was thinking about doing that for the second solution as well, but used `<` instead of `<=`, which didn't work, so came up with a longer solution, but updated my answer with your idea if you don't mind :)

Comment: You can simplify the (second) sort call by comparing tuples, compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612765

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the idea, I also included that solution in my answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
let dd = [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]
let res = dd.sorted { f, s in
    dd.filter { $0 == f }.count <   dd.filter { $0 == s }.count 
} 
print(res) // [1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: I wonder if this is O(n). – Note also that the sort is not *stable,* there is no guarantee that the order of numbers which occur equally often is preserved.

Comment: @MartinR i don't think such problem be solved with in O(n) , sure there may be other less extensive answer also

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sh_Khan, but expected output should be `[1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]`

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to sort with O(n) time complexity. Look at the worst case complexity for popular algorithms at [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts)

The better worst-case time complexity is O(nlogn). Here is how we can solve it with O(nlogn) time complexity:

```
    let array = [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]

    extension Array where Element: Comparable & Hashable {
        func countableSorted() -> [Element] {
            var counts = [Element: Int]()
            // O(n)
            for element in self {
                counts[element] = (counts[element] ?? 0) + 1
            }

            // I think that standart method uses O(nlogn) time complexity.
            // O(nlogn) + O(n) approximately equal to O(nlogn).
            let sorted = counts.sorted { item1, item2 -> Bool in
                if item2.value > item1.value {
                    return true
                }

                if item2.value == item1.value {
                    return item2.key > item1.key
                }

                return false
            }

            var result = [Element]()
            // O(n)
            for item in sorted {
                let items = Array(repeating: item.key, count: item.value)
                result.append(contentsOf: items)
            }

            // Total time complexity for worst case scenario is O(nlogn)

            return result
        }
    }

    print(array.countableSorted())

    // Output: [1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputArray = [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]
var map:[Int: Int] = [:]
for element in inputArray {
    let count = map[element]
    if count == nil {
        map[element] = 1
    } else {
        map[element] = count! + 1
    }
}
var keysArray = map.keys
let sortedKeys = keysArray.sorted { (number1, number2) -> Bool in
    if map[number1]! == map[number2]! {
        return number1 < number2
    } else {
        return map[number1]! < map[number2]!
    }
}
var finalArray: [Int] = []
for element in sortedKeys {
    for _ in 1...map[element]! {
        finalArray.append(element)
    }
}
print(finalArray)
```

Time Complexity: O(nlogn)

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. Edited. 
Further, optional checking shall be done as well. But this solves the basic problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code, this worked properly.

```
var inputArray = [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]
inputArray.sort()
let freq = inputArray.sorted { f, s in
    inputArray.filter { $0 == f}.count < inputArray.filter { $0 == s}.count
}
print(freq)
```

Not sure about the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a **solution in O(n)**

Sorting takes O(nLogn) but this question can also be solved without using sorting by help of HashMap in Java because **it contains the pairs sorted in accordance to the key.**

```
import java.util.*; 

class Simple 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] arg) 
    {  int inputArray[] = {1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2};
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); 
        Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
       for(int i: inputArray)
      {
                  if(map.get(i) == null){
                 map.put(i, 1) ;
                  }
                  else{
                  int a = map.get(i);
                  map.put(i,a+1);
                 }
      }

        // using for-each loop for iteration over Map.entrySet() 
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if(map2.get(entry.getValue()) == null){
                map2.put(entry.getValue(), new ArrayList<Integer>()) ;
            }
            map2.get(entry.getValue()).add(entry.getKey());
        }

        for(Map.Entry<Integer,List<Integer>> entry : map2.entrySet()){
            for(int j=0; j<entry.getValue().size(); j++){
                for(int i=0; i<entry.getKey(); i++){
                System.out.print(entry.getValue().get(j) + " ");
            }
            }

        }    
    }         

}
```

1. In First for loop I am iterating through array saving pair of (value,Occurrence)  in map1(HashMap). This will take O(n) as HashMap put operation(insertion) takes O(1).
2. In second for loop I am iterating map1 and inserting pair of **(occurrence, list of numbers in the given array with that occurrence)** in map2(HashMap2).
3. Now in last for loop I am iterating through map2 and printing all the lists one by one it means I am printing each element of given array once i.e. I am iterating through the list of each key and printing each element of the list **key** number of times. So this would also take O(n).

[more about HashMap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-hashmap-java/)
**Time Complexity : O(n)**

**Swift Version of above code**

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable & Hashable {
func sortByNumberOfOccurences() -> [Element] {
    let occurencesDict = self.reduce(into: [Element:Int](), { currentResult, element in
        currentResult[element, default: 0] += 1
    })
    let dict = occurencesDict.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
    var dictioanary = [Int:Array]()
    for (element,occurence) in dict {
        if dictioanary[occurence] == nil
        {
            dictioanary[occurence] = Array()
        }
        dictioanary[occurence]?.append(element)
    }


    var resultArray = Array()
    let finalDict = dictioanary.sorted(by: {$0.0  < $1.0})
    for (frequency,allValuesOccuringWithThisFrequncy) in finalDict {
       for i in allValuesOccuringWithThisFrequncy
       {
        var j = 0
        while(j < frequency)
        {
            resultArray.append(i)
            j = j + 1
        }
       }
    }
    print(resultArray)
    return resultArray
}
```

}

**Time Complexity in Swift O(nLogn)**

Comment: Can you try the same approach in swift?

Comment: @Bappaditya Hi I tried to write the code in swift. I am  adding the code. But as Dictionary in Swift does not maintain the order we need to apply the sort method in that and it makes complexity O(nLogn). But in java HashMap insert pairs in sorted way on the basis  of  key. I wish  we had a similar type of collection in Swift too. Sad :( I think we need to  write our own HashMap in Swift :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It worked for me like a charm :)

```
func numberOfOccurences(in array: [Int], of element: Int) -> Int {
    let object = NSCountedSet(array: array)
    return object.count(for: element)
}

var inputArray = [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]

var uniqueElements = Array(Set(inputArray))

var otherArray: [Int] = []

var duplicateElements = uniqueElements.filter { (element) -> Bool in
    return (inputArray.contains(element) && numberOfOccurences(in: inputArray, of: element) > 1)
}

uniqueElements = uniqueElements.filter({ !duplicateElements.contains($0) }).sorted()

for item in duplicateElements {
    let occurences = numberOfOccurences(in: inputArray, of: item)
    for _ in 0...occurences - 1 {
        otherArray.append(item)
    }
}

otherArray = otherArray.sorted()

duplicateElements.removeAll()

let mergedArray = uniqueElements + otherArray

print(mergedArray)
```

Comment: If you are declaring a loop condition of `x...y - 1`, it makes more sense to do `x..<y`.

Comment: For the input `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` your code produces the result `[3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]`, which looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of sorting can be achieved in O(n), with something like the following:

```
let input = [1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2]

// build the frequency dictionary (easy task)
let frequencies = input.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1] = ($0[$1] ?? 0) + 1 }

// allocate a 2-D array of ints, each item in this array will hold the numbers that
// appear I times in the input array
let frequencyTable: [[Int]] = frequencies.reduce(into: Array(repeating: [Int](), count: input.count)) {
    // substracting one as arrays are zero indexed
    // we can't get of of bounds here since the maximum frequency is the 
    // number of elements in the input array
    // Also replicating the numbers by their frequency, to have
    // the same contents as in the input array
    $0[$1.value - 1] += Array(repeating: $1.key, count: $1.value)
}

// lastly, simply flatten the 2-D array to get the output we need
let output = frequencyTable.flatMap { $0 }

print(output)
```

Sample result:

```
[4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Note that the order of numbers with the same frequency might differ based on how the dictionary hash function works.

Also we sacrifice space (allocated 2-D array) in favour of time.

The `frequencyTable` contents will look similar to this (again the order of 1, 4, 3 might differ):

```
[[4, 3, 1], [2, 2], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Otherwise known as *Counting sort*