# How can I check the embedded functions definitions in swift?

Tags: swift, function, sorting

I am learning `Swift` by myself on **MacOS**. When following the tutorial and practicing the array function: `<array_name>.sort()`, I can get it executed but I always wonder how it works and what is the actual algorithm inside it. 
So is there any way to check the certain function definitions?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677026/swift-sorting-algorithm-implementation

Comment: Thanks! I got new jungle to discover!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the **declaration** of the function/class, you can command-click on it. If you want the **documentation**, you can either option-click it or check it on the [API reference page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/). If you want to see the **implementation details** of the Swift standard library, check the source code [here at GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift). If the implementation you are checking is in a non open-source APIs though, you can't quite check it.

Comment: Thanks, the cmd-click and option-click unveiled lots of declaration details.

Comment: That GitHub website is very helpful now I am digging myself in it.