# Sort(by:) method / Need explanation

Tags: swift, sorting, methods, syntax, closures

Came across this new “sort(by:)” method in my study book, without any reasonable explanation for how and why it works, with this for a code example:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 6, 9, 8]

let sortClosure = { (a: Int, b: Int) -> Bool in
    return a < b
}

numbers.sort(by: sortClosure)
print(numbers)
```

With my own research I found that if **a** (first element of the array) needs to be before **b** (second element of the array), the closure returns **true** and sorts the array that way.

But my compiler says `return a < b == false` and `return a > b == true` and I can't understand why, because how can 2 be less than 1?

Please, help me to understand what's wrong with my compiler or what I can't understand it's working from the `sort(by:)` method?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the compiler thinks 2 is less than 1? Add the following code line in the closure and see for yourself what happens, `print(a, b, a < b)`

Comment: Yes, now I see. But why it takes 2 as **a** and 1 as **b**? I thought that **a** is the first element of array @JoakimDanielson

Comment: That is the cause of how the underlying sort algorithm traverses the array. I am no expert but see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677026/what-sorting-algorithm-does-swift-implement-for-its-standard-library) if you want to start diving deeper into sorting algorithms.

Comment: Do not care about the sort algorithm behind the `sort()` method. It could be bubble sort, or any other one (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). Just focus on "I have two elements, ie the closure parameters, compare them", that's all.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I understand how to work with it in the future. I don't want to dive deeper into sorting algorithms for now, because I'm a newbie. So I'll use @Larme method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various [sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm): Bubble Sort, Quicksort, merge sort, etc.
They have they pros/cons, mostly about : memory use, complexity, etc. In a nutshell: Will it create another full array or more in memory while sorting? Will it takes a lot of time if the array if big? etc.

In [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677026/what-sorting-algorithm-does-swift-implement-for-its-standard-library), you might see which algorithm seems to be used, and it seems that the algorithm changed in the past.
And tomorrow, the algorithm might change or even adapt (like: if there are less than 1k elements, do sort logic 1, but if there are more, do sort logic 2 because it's less expensive on memory and you have not a lot of RAM currently, etc.)

But as you want to use the high level method `sort(by:)`, and not implement yourself the algorithm, do not focus on it.

Just focus on what to do in the closure which is quite simple:

- you have 2 elements in parameters
- retrieve from them the infos to compare: be it they raw value, a computed property, another related value you want etc.
- compare these two values: return true if you want the first parameter to be placed before the second one, false in the other case.

You can print the value if you want:

```
let returnValue = a < b
print("Comparing \(a) vs \(b) and returning: \(returnValue)")
return returnValue
```

In your simple case, you are comparing the raw value which are `Int`.

So the full lines of the previous explanation are:

```
let valueFromAToCompare = a
let valueFromBToCompare = b
return valueFromAToCompare < valueFromBToCompare
```

Which can obviously be simplified as `return a < b`.

If we had structs like that in our array, and you want to sort according to its numbers:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let number: Int
    let subNumber: String
}
```

The closure would be:

```
let valueFromAToCompare = a.number
let valueFromBToCompare = b.number
return valueFromAToCompare < valueFromBToCompare
```

Which can be simplified into: `return a.number < b.number`.

But as you can guess, there can be later more complex sort logic: compare the numbers, but if the `number`s are equals, then compare the `subNumber`, hence the closure which can let you put your whole logic:

```
if a.number == b.number {
    return a.subNumber < b.subNumber
} else {
    return a.number < b.number
}
```

Of course, it can simplified or written differently, but that's to make the example more comprehensible.